# Purpose Of Monitor.Pulse

Tags: c#, multithreading

I just want to make sure I understand something here. If I obtain a lock with `Monitor.Enter` or `lock` do I need to call `Pulse` before releasing the lock?

```
Monitor.Enter

Monitor.Pulse // Is that neccessary?

Monitor.Exit
```

I was always led to believe that a `Monitor.Exit` call would implicitly invoke `Monitor.Pulse`. Is that actually true?

I'm not exactly sure when would you would use `Pulse`. That is what is causing confusion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `Pulse`... but it won't be done automatically when you exit, either.

`Pulse` and `PulseAll` are used in conjunction with `Wait` for signalling purposes.

See the second half of [this page](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/deadlocks.shtml) for more details (ignore the deadlocking bit, basically :)