# Synchronization between multiple threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I have few threads in which are called two or more methods. I need to synchronize them, so I tried to use `barrier` class:

```
Barrier barrier = new Barrier(2); // 2 = #threads participating.
bool complete = false;
TaskFactory factory = Task.Factory;

// Start tasks
Task task_1 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    process_1.Server("1 and 2");
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 2 to catch up.
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 2 to print "2" and set complete = true.

    if (complete)
    {
        process_1.Server("1 and 3");
    }
});
Task task_6 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    process_6.Server("6 and 4");
    process_6.Server("6 and 3");
});
Task task_2 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 1 to print "1".
    process_2.Client("1 and 2");
    complete = true;
    barrier.SignalAndWait(); // Wait for task 1 to read complete as true.

    process_2.Server("2 and 5");
    process_2.Server("2 and 3");
});
Task task_4 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    process_4.Client("6 and 4");
    process_4.Server("4 and 7");
    process_4.Server("4 and 3");
});
Task task_5 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    process_5.Client("2 and 5");
    process_5.Server("5 and 3");
});
Task task_7 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    process_7.Client("4 and 7");
    process_7.Server("7 and 3");
});
Task task_3 = factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    process_3.Client("1 and 3");
    process_3.Client("2 and 3");
    process_3.Client("4 and 3");
    process_3.Client("5 and 3");
    process_3.Client("6 and 3");
    process_3.Client("7 and 3");
});

task_3.Wait();
```

I need to ensure consequence between calling methods from different threads for example: `process_1.Server("1 and 2");` and `process_2.Client("1 and 2");`. Calling `Client` method before `Server` is not acceptable. All the dependencies: `{process_1.Server("1 and 2"); process_2.Client("1 and 2");}, {process_2.Server("2 and 5"); process_5.Client("2 and 5");}, {process_6.Server("6 and 4"); process_4.Client("6 and 4");}, {process_4.Server("4 and 7"); process_7.Client("4 and 7");}, {process_1.Server("1 and 3"); process_3.Client("1 and 3");}, {process_2.Server("2 and 3"); process_3.Client("2 and 3");}, {process_4.Server("4 and 3"); process_3.Client("4 and 3");}, {process_5.Server("5 and 3"); process_3.Client("5 and 3");}, {process_6.Server("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3");}, {process_7.Server("7 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3");}.`

Between elemets `{...}` and `{...}` there are no dependecies. So it is possible to execute `{process_6.Server("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3");}, {process_7.Server("7 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3");}` or vice versa `{process_7.Server("7 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3");}, {process_6.Server("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3");}`. There are dependencies between elements into `{...}` which I wrote. Can you help me to solve this problem? I can not figure out how to implement this.

Thank you very much!

Full programm code:

```
class Pipe
{
    public string message;

    public Pipe()
    {
        message = "";
    }

    public Pipe(string message)
    {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void Server(object pipeName)
    {
        // Create a name pipe
        using (NamedPipeServerStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipeName.ToString()))
        {
            // Wait for a connection
            pipeStream.WaitForConnection();

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(pipeStream))
            {
                sw.AutoFlush = true;
                sw.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }

        Console.Write("Communication between processes " + pipeName.ToString());
    }

    public void Client(object pipeName)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream pipeStream = new NamedPipeClientStream(pipeName.ToString()))
        {
            // The connect function will indefinately wait for the pipe to become available
            // If that is not acceptable specify a maximum waiting time (in ms)
            pipeStream.Connect();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(pipeStream))
            {
                // We read a line from the pipe and print it together with the current time
                message += sr.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(": client received message.\n");
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

            Pipe process_1 = new Pipe("Test message from process #1.");
            Pipe process_2 = new Pipe();
            Pipe process_3 = new Pipe();
            Pipe process_4 = new Pipe();
            Pipe process_5 = new Pipe();
            Pipe process_6 = new Pipe("Test message from process #6.");
            Pipe process_7 = new Pipe();

            TaskFactory factory = Task.Factory;

            // Start tasks
            Task task_1 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_1.Server("1 and 2"); process_1.Server("1 and 3"); });
            Task task_6 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_6.Server("6 and 4"); process_6.Server("6 and 3"); });
            Task task_2 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_2.Client("1 and 2"); process_2.Server("2 and 5"); process_2.Server("2 and 3"); });
            Task task_4 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_4.Client("6 and 4"); process_4.Server("4 and 7"); process_4.Server("4 and 3"); });
            Task task_5 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_5.Client("2 and 5"); process_5.Server("5 and 3"); });
            Task task_7 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_7.Client("4 and 7"); process_7.Server("7 and 3"); });
            Task task_3 = factory.StartNew(() => { process_3.Client("1 and 3"); process_3.Client("2 and 3"); process_3.Client("4 and 3"); process_3.Client("5 and 3"); process_3.Client("6 and 3"); process_3.Client("7 and 3"); });

            task_3.Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a brief explanation what the variables `process_n`'s types are? Is it a class written on your own, containing the two methods `Server` and `Client` with `string` as sincle input argument and `void` return value? Have you tried to minimize your problem first e.g. starting with only 2 threads, then subsequently adding complexity by adding further threads?

Comment: I agree with @isi, my brain rolled over while reading the question...

Comment: I added code of full programm. Yes, you understood correct: it is a class written on my own, containing the two methods Server and Client with string as sincle input argument and void return value

Comment: @HABJAN, Sorry, I tried to explain my task. The problem is: if I add cycle in main class sometimes Client method starts befor Server or two servers are starting consequtively before client does. So in console I have `Communication between processes 1 and 3Communication between processes 1 and 3` instead of `Communication between processes 1 and 3: client received message.` Can you help me to synchronize this tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you need to make sure that never a call to the method `Client` is performed before `Server` has been called on your `Pipe` object. I have reduced your example to and added a test class to document the behaviour. The reduced code contains of a much simpler form of your `Pipe` class, which now only puts some string on a list passed in as a parameter in the c'tor, instead of creating real pipes.

The synchronization is handled completely by a decorating subclass of `Pipe` called `BlockingPipe`. `BlockingPipe` uses some low level mechanisms called conditional locks or condition synchronization. Jeff Magee and Jeff Kramer wrote a great book about concurrency patterns and their application in java take a look at [condition sync. (java) slides 12-14](http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~jnm/book/pdf/ch5.pdf) or for c# [condition sync. in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902137/condition-synchronization) especially take a look at @john skeet's answer he points to another good reference. The pattern includes using the [pulse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100166/purpose-of-monitor-pulse) to notify all waiting threads.

Enough theory, back to your code. Here is the simplified `Pipe` class:

```
class Pipe
{
    internal static int counter = 0;
    private readonly int id = counter++;
    private readonly IList<string> calls;
    public Pipe(IList<string> calls) { this.calls = calls; }
    public virtual void Server(string s) { EnqueeCall(s, "server"); }
    public virtual void Client(string s) { EnqueeCall(s, "client"); }
    private void EnqueeCall(string s, string actor)
    {
        calls.Add(actor + id + " processes " + s);
    }
}
```

Now the `BlockingPipe` class uses condition synchronization. The conditions and states for a given `BlockingPipe` object can be modelled as a finite state machine. Where your `BlockingPipe` can be in two states - ServerCalled and ServerNotCalled. The state is used to maintain this dependency for each method. The subclass delegates to the base class' implementations in order provide a better separation usual logic and synchronization logic:

```
class BlockingPipe : Pipe
{
    public BlockingPipe(IList<string> calls) : base(calls) { }
    private enum State { ServerCalled, ServerNotCalled }
    private State state = State.ServerNotCalled;
    public override void Server(string s)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            base.Server(s);
            state = State.ServerCalled;
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
        }
    }
    public override void Client(string s)
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            while (state != State.ServerCalled)
                Monitor.Wait(this, 200);
            base.Client(s);
        }
    }
}
```

The last step is to test the class.

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeTestClass
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) Test();
    }

    private static void Test()
    {
        Pipe.counter = 0;
        var list = new List<string>();
        var p = new BlockingPipe(list);
        var f = Task.Factory;
        var b = new Barrier(3);
        f.StartNew(() => { p.Client("asdf"); b.SignalAndWait(); });
        f.StartNew(() => { p.Server("qwer"); b.SignalAndWait(); });
        b.SignalAndWait();
        var exp = String.Join("\n", 
          new[] { "server0 processes qwer", "client0 processes asdf" });
        var act = String.Join("\n", list);
        Assert.AreEqual(exp, act);
    }
}
```

The `Test` method can be called as many times as you like (hopefully) always producing the correct behaviour. I hope this scales up to your use case. The test checks if the calls being performed on the `Pipe` have been of that form:

server0 processes qwer
   client0 processes asdf

Both created threads share the same instance of the `Pipe` object. To test the robustness of this solution i have added a for loop calling the actual `Test` method a hundred times, always producing the same result. The only flaw i noticed was that the implementation of the condition syncrhonization pattern itself didn't work without adding a timeout on the `Monitor.Wait` call inside the `while` loop of `BlockingPipe`. Because i had a thread waiting forever to recieve a `Pulse` but the pulsing thread already returned, which may requires to add another condition for that circumstance as well.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a custom `SynchronizationContext` with its own queue of tasks. And then you choose which tasks you want to execute, based on their dependencies. This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/01/20/10259049.aspx) can show you how you can set up the custom context and how to use it.

Comment: I read this article. But I do not understand how to stop implementation of one thread and to resume it after some events.